# javascript plus and minus script stop working in loop because of square brackets

Tags: javascript

I have a cart where the product and quantity gets displayed in a loop. I have added the html below but the values and quantity values will be replaced by php output in a loop..

```js
function incrementValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
  alert(fieldName);
  var parent = $(e.target).closest('span');
  var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);

  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
  } else {
    parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
  }
}

function decrementValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
  var parent = $(e.target).closest('span');
  var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);

  if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
    parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
  } else {
    parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
  }
}

$('.updown').on('click', '.button-plus', function(e) {
  incrementValue(e);
});

$('.updown').on('click', '.button-minus', function(e) {
  decrementValue(e);
});
```

```css
               
input,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


.updown input[type='button'] {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  min-width: 38px;
  width: auto;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.updown .button-minus,
.updown .button-plus {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 38px;
  position: relative;
}

.updown .quantity-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 38px;
  left: -6px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 62px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  resize: vertical;
}

.button-plus {
  left: -13px;
}

input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="updown float-end">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
  <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="5" name="quantity[4]" class="quantity-field">
  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
</span>

<span class="updown float-end">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
  <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="6" name="quantity[8]" class="quantity-field">
  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
</span>

<span class="updown float-end">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
  <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="7" name="quantity[6]" class="quantity-field">
  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
</span>
```

it used to work but I had to add the square brackets in the name field to output the unique name name="quantity[6] otherwise it over writes.. it breaks the javascript any help will be very welcome thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some enhancement of your code.

There are `prev()` and `next()` function from jquery which save your time to find the input from parent to child.

The error `$ is not undefined` is caused by you didn't import jquery.

```js
function incrementValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fieldName = $(e.target).attr('data-field');
  let inputEle = $(e.target).prev()
  var currentVal = parseInt(inputEle.val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    inputEle.val(currentVal + 1);
  } else {
    inputEle.val(0);
  }

}

function decrementValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
  let inputEle = $(e.target).next()
  var currentVal = parseInt(inputEle.val());

  if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
    inputEle.val(currentVal - 1);
  } else {
    inputEle.val(0);
  }
}

$('.updown').on('click', '.button-plus', function(e) {
  incrementValue(e);
});

$('.updown').on('click', '.button-minus', function(e) {
  decrementValue(e);
});
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


.updown input[type='button'] {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  min-width: 38px;
  width: auto;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.updown .button-minus,
.updown .button-plus {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 38px;
  position: relative;
}

.updown .quantity-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 38px;
  left: -6px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 62px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  resize: vertical;
}

.button-plus {
  left: -13px;
}

input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="updown float-end">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
  <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="5" name="quantity[4]" class="quantity-field">
  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
</span>

<span class="updown float-end">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
  <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="6" name="quantity[8]" class="quantity-field">
  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
</span>

<span class="updown float-end">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
  <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="7" name="quantity[6]" class="quantity-field">
  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
</span>
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, no I did link to jquery, but I placed the javascript at the top (not bottom) of the page and coppied yours in and it worked, thanks anyways !!

Comment: @gabrielkolbe please mark my post as answered if it worked :) thanks